# DevExtreme datagrid returning cell value on button click

Tags: javascript, datagrid, devexpress, devextreme

In my project I have a simple datagrid set up as follows in a razor page:

```
<div id="Datagrid" dx-item-alias="itemData">
    @(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<Batch>().ID("gridContainer")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add().CellTemplate(
          @<text>
            @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
            .ID("sendButton")
            .Text("Select Batch")
            .OnClick("onItemClick")     
            )                          
          </text>);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.Id);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.Name).Caption("Name");
    })
    .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("Batches").LoadAction("GetAllEntries").Key("BatchId")) 
    ) 
</div>
```

The data is loaded into datagrid via a WebApi I've created. I'm omitting that code from my question as it doesn't add anything of value.

In the first column I have added a button for every row that gets rendered. What I want to happen is when I click on this button, the value of cell Id next to it, is rendered on the screen/console/whatever. I just need to grab the value.

A rough visual of this is:

```
       | Id  | Name
-------|-----|------
button |  1  | John
button |  2  | Chris
```

So when I press the button next to cell containing an Id value of 1, I want to grab this value and print out on the screen or console. When I press the button next to id value of 2 I want to grab the value of "2" and do the same.

I've the following js code trying to achieve this:

```
function onItemClick(e) {
    DevExpress.ui.notify("The " + e.component.option("value"));
  }
```

However, this isn't working. What do I need to do in order to get the correct cell value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use the approach described in the [ASP.NET MVC Controls -> Fundamentals -> Implementing Templates -> Accessing Template Parameters](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/ASP.NET_MVC_Controls/Fundamentals/#Implementing_Templates/Accessing_Template_Parameters) article. I.e. inside your Button OnClick event handler, you can use the `data` variable to access the current grid row:

```
columns.Add().CellTemplate(
    @<text>
        @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
                .ID("sendButton")
                .Text("Select Batch")
                .OnClick("function () { onItemClick(data); }")
        )
    </text>);
```

Then, the `onItemClick` method will look like:

```
function onItemClick(data) {
    DevExpress.ui.notify(data.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom cell template `cellTemplate` callback to receive the complete row data  on cell button click.

```
cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
                    $("<div>")
                        .append($("<button>", { text:"Button","data-key":JSON.stringify(options.data), "click": function(e){
                           console.log("Button Click Row Data => ",JSON.parse(e.target.getAttribute('data-key')));
                        }.bind(this) }))
                        .appendTo(container);
                }
```

I have created an jsfiddle demo for reference - https://jsfiddle.net/hzgfetLj/2/

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I need this to work on a button press, not when the cell is clicked.

Comment: @N0xus I have updated the answer to implement on button click. Updated JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hzgfetLj/2/